# Tranformdata in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to tranform  data from raw data to goal/output.  I know the logic when writing basic python but i am failing to implement in pandas.

```
for i in range (0, qty[i]);
    number =[] 
    np.append number [start[i]+1]
```

I am failing to apply the same logic in pandas data frame

sample data

| item id | qty | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1000 | 1003 |

desired output

| item id | qty | start | end | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1000 | 1003 | 1000 |
| 1 | 3 | 1000 | 1003 | 1001 |
| 1 | 3 | 1000 | 1003 | 1002 |

Comment: I don't know what the sample data looks like or the result of sample should compute to. Can you clarify with sample data and results?

Comment: I have edited  the question and added the raw data and desired out come

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['end'].sub(df['start']))]

df['number'] = df['start'].add(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount())

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   item id  qty  start   end  number
0        1    3   1000  1003    1000
1        1    3   1000  1003    1001
2        1    3   1000  1003    1002
```